# Implementation of Least Square Method to approximate a cloud of points (Python)

Tags: python, least-squares, approximation

I need to implement the least square method in Python.
I can't use the spicy lib, I need to implement my own method.

The objective is to be able to approximate a few points given as input, and to get the equation as the answer :

```
x = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
y = [1, 3, 5, 10, 15]
 
def leastSquare(x,y):
   # (Let's say we chose the "a*x + b" model.)

   # Should return : 28/13*x - 118/65
```

I've searched quite a long time but couldn't find anything that did the job.

Comment: For linear regression using basic Python (i.e. no libraries) check [classic approach linear regression](https://relate.cs.illinois.edu/course/cs357-f15/file-version/59babe8be91b4665456aae2abfdc1e1e732643ec/media/least-squares/linregr_least_squares_fit.html#Least-squares-fit-implementations)

Comment: I'll take a look now, thank you.

Comment: This actually worked. Thank you so much!